# Keeping the potential for inlining when there are some recursive cases

Tags: haskell, optimization, ghc

Consider the following data type, which is only intended to be illistrative:

```
data D where
  D1 :: Int -> D
  D2 :: String -> D
  DJ :: D -> D -> D
```

And perhaps a function on it, say `toString`:

```
{-# INLINE toString #-}
toString x = case x of
  (D1 x) -> "Int: show x"
  (D2 x) -> "String: show x"
  (DJ x y) -> "(" ++ toString x ++ "," ++ toString y ++ ")"
```

(It's worth noting what I'm doing has nothing to do with printing, this is just an illustrative example)

So what I find is that by defining `toString` like this makes my program 15 times faster:

```
{-# INLINE toString #-}
toString x = case x of
  (D1 x) -> "Int: show x"
  (D2 x) -> "String: show x"
  (DJ x y) -> undefined
```

What's happened is that `toString` is now able to be inlined by GHC. This allows for a whole lot of optimisations down the road. The `DJ` case is what was causing problems. So then I tried this:

```
{-# INLINE toString #-}
toString x = case x of
  (D1 x) -> intShow x
  (D2 x) -> strShow x
  _ -> go x
  where
    go (D1 x) -> intShow x
    go (D2 x) -> strShow x
    go (DJ x y) -> "(" ++ go x ++ "," ++ go y ++ ")"
    intShow x = "Int: show x"
    strShow x = "String: show x"
```

This actually means it compiles fast. The reason is (I'm pretty sure anyway) because `toString` is no longer recursive. `go` is, but `toString` isn't. So the compiler will happily inline `toString`, allowing for more optimisations down the road.

But the above code, in my opinion, is ugly.

Like I said, the function I have is more complex than this, and this sort of issue occurs throughout my code. I've got a data type with lots of constructors, some simple and some recursive. Whenever I define a recursive case however, it slows down even the simple cases. Is there a way to keep the top function inlining without uglifing the code like I have above?

Comment: Lot of questions concerning inlining lately…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have no elegant solution, but perhaps something like this could work. Untested.

```
{-# INLINE toString #-}
toString x = go (fix go)  -- equivalent to (fix go), but unrolled once
  where
  {-# INLINE go #-}
  go _ (D1 x) -> intShow x
  go _ (D2 x) -> strShow x
  go k (DJ x y) -> "(" ++ k x ++ "," ++ k y ++ ")"
  intShow x = "Int: show x"
  strShow x = "String: show x"
```

Comment: anything with `fix` is beautiful.

Comment: @WillNess Definitely. Yet, this kind of code is easier to write than to read, IMO. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you've correctly identified the issue and what has to be done to solve it, the usual (and I agree not super satisfying):

- mark `INLINE`
- eta fiddling so that the left-hand side is fully applied at the call site
- add a trivial layer of indirection so that the function is not recursive

But something like this should be sufficient here I *think*:

```
{-# INLINE toString #-}
toString x = go x where
 go case x of
  (D1 x) -> "Int: show x"
  (D2 x) -> "String: show x"
  (DJ x y) -> "(" ++ go x ++ "," ++ go y ++ ")"
```

As chi points out in their answer it seems what you're doing here is a manual single level of loop unrolling; it's easy to see why this would be faster for, say:

```
(DJ (D1 0) (D2 "zero"))
```

But less obvious how much better this would be when you had deeply nested `DJ`s for instance. I would be curious to know, and to see how you're benchmarking.

Most of the time we care about inlining in this way because our `x` is polymorphic and we would like a function we call on `x` in the body to be specialized. Or we want the result to stay an unboxed type.

Answer (score 1):

I've given @chi above the tick mark for his great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42223511/525980) involving `fix` which did do the job. But was a bit fiddly because in my case my recursion is polymorphic (which `fix` monomorphises) so I had to roll my own `fix`.

I also feared that by passing the recursive argument in instead of calling it directly might further confuse the compiler for the recursive cases.

But inspired by @chi's answer, and thinking that I basically want two functions the same, a non-recursive one and a recursive one, I've then realised I can do that, like so:

```
import Data.Proxy (Proxy(Proxy))

toString x = go' (Proxy :: Proxy True)
  {-# SPECIALISE INLINE go' :: Proxy True -> String #-}
  go' :: (Proxy a) -> String
  go' _ = case x of
    (D1 x) -> "Int: show x"
    (D2 x) -> "String: show x"
    (DJ x y) -> "(" ++ go x ++ "," ++ go y ++ ")"
  go = go' (Proxy :: Proxy False)
```

Because of the specialisation for `go'`, the compiler will emit two `go'` functions, one for when the `Proxy` argument is `True`, and another for when it it `False`.

The first, when it is `True`, is not recursive, it never calls itself (it only calls the `False` version). So if we make a specialisation of this, it's inlinable. As `go' (True)` is not recursive, so is `toString`, as all `toString` does is call `go' (True)`, so `toString` is then inlinable.

This approach needs a little boilerplate but at least the length of the boilerplate is constant, it doesn't increase with the number of constructors you need to deal with.